# How do I use this monaco library in an electron app?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, monaco-editor, building

How can I use monaco in my electron app? out [this](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/tree/master/example) example: What's the proper way to do that?  i'm open to new suggestions. I throughout into building a micro frontends but it's not that nice in react/electron and in the end i would have to include the final index output file using iframe. I wish I could use something we do with dlls in desktop application. note: i'm new to react and electron, perdon mystakes that seems so simple.

Well, I tried to "merge" as needed both webpack configs. Is this the way to go? so far i couldn't make it. I added:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vscode': require.resolve('@codingame/monaco-languageclient/lib/vscode-compatibility')
    }
```

but it cannot find the vscode module, i'm getting the error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'vscode' in 'C:\Users\jjj\Desktop\merge\Newton\node_modules\vscode-languageclient\lib\common' even tho the package is installed.`

I also tried to add `"editor.worker": 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js'`  in the entry section but I got the error:

An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename index.js (chunks 179 and 915)
Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename index.js (chunks 179 and 915)

I did plan to -- assuming it's the proper way to go ---, once managed to fix this webpackes merge, I'd include the main file with the contents:

```
    require('monaco-editor');
    (self as any).MonacoEnvironment = {
        getWorkerUrl: () => './editor.worker.bundle.js'
    }
    require('./client');
```

then have
`<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>`
somewhere to show the editor and the `<script src="main.bundle.js"></script>` wouldn't be needed due to the fact it would be included in the webscript's output javascript bundle file, used elsewhere by the entire application.

Comment: Do you use React? If you use `React`, you can use `@monaco-editor/react`. I checked how to add `@monaco-editor/react` to `Electron`, but I haven't checked how to add `monaco-editor` without a `React`. Even though `React` was used, if you want, I will answer the way I know.

Comment: @lowfront Yes, I do use React. Is this component uptodate/maintained? and can I use the language server protocol like in the client.ts? https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/blob/master/example/src/client.ts if I can do all that, I'll be more than happy to accept your answer!

Comment: My understanding of mono-languageclient is insufficient. I'll look into it more and answer it!

Comment: @lowfront Alright then, take a look on what it takes to make this run: https://medium.com/dscddu/language-server-protocol-adding-support-for-multiple-language-servers-to-monaco-editor-a3c35e42a98d if you manage to make all this work using this component, i'll gladly mark it accepted answer

Comment: Hi! I've been a little busy. Interested in this matter, I did some research. I tried the medium post you sent me, but it didn't work. My problems were as follows. [link](https://github.com/wylieconlon/jsonrpc-ws-proxy/issues/10). However, I have confirmed that the Electron example in the Monaco editor repository works. [link](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples/electron-esm-webpack).

Comment: So I have two questions. Do you know an example of a monacoeditor in which the typecript language server operates? Don't you want it to work with a worker like the monaco editor repository I wrote? (I confirmed that the Walker method also emphasizes grammar and detects errors.)

Comment: @lowfront Hi, I've never tried to use it as typescript, I was trying to use the D LPS server... it was working without electron, like in the code sample i sent you, i started getting issues when i tried to use it directly within the electron application. I was getting this error: https://github.com/MassMessage/vscodefailure I'd like to the monaco editor repo you wrote, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various errors may occur depending on the bundler configuration, so I made it simple example by referring to codes [monaco-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples/electron-esm-webpack) and [monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/tree/master/example). Both repositories work after build, so I separated the main process and renderer process folders to avoid overlapping outputs. Maybe this is related to Forge's error.

I created an Electron renderer code using `monaco-languageclient`'s client code, and in the main process, run `monaco-languageclient`'s server. Therefore, both processes must share the same web socket port. You can also erase the [following lines](https://github.com/lowfront/monaco-electron/blob/master/src/main/index.ts#L2) and run LanguageServer externally.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/lowfront/monaco-electron) without the iframe.